# Errror to parsing the data from Nested JSON format

Tags: python, json, parsing

Hello i'm quite newbie in python, really need a solution.

So, i've got the JSON data from marketplace website that contains all review data. But i want to get "reviewCreateTime" data only. I need to parse them.

This is the JSON data Tree:

[image]

this is my code:

```
items = []
for item in obj:
items.append(item['reviewCreateTime'])
```

[image]

But, i still have an error message

[image]

Can anyone solve this case?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do not post image of code, copy paste code instead. Also read [mcve] to make your post suits SO standards.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
for item in obj["data"]["ProductReviewListQuery"]["list"]
    items.append(item["reviewCreateTime"])
```

Comment: can you post your json file here